Gaussian integral, boson
I have the following Euclidean action:
$$
S(\phi,\lambda) = \int d^3x \phi^*(\hbar \partial_\tau -\hbar \mu -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}+\lambda )\phi
$$
where $\lambda$ is an auxiliary field, but since the action is quadratic in $\phi$ I should be able to integrate it out to obtain the determinant of some matrix:
$
\left[\begin{array}{ll}
\phi & \phi^* 
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
....\\
..... \\
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
\phi \\
\phi^*
\end{array}\right]
$
but then what I obtain is
$\frac{1}{2}\left[\begin{array}{c}
0 \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad  \hbar \partial_\tau -\hbar \mu -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}+\lambda  \\
-\hbar \partial_\tau -\hbar \mu -\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}+\lambda \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad  0 \\
\end{array}\right]
$
How can I obtain a matrix with elements on the diagonal? should I transform it after, or write it on another basis?

If you haven't figured it out by now: the conjugate should be $(\phi^{*} ; \phi)$.
